# Referencia a main sin definir

Tags: c, linux

Al tratar de compilar el siguiente código por línea de comandos me devuelve el siguiente error:

> "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: En la función _start': (.text+0x20): referencia a main' sin definir
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TAM 10

main()
{
char arreglo[TAM];
char *apc;
apc=arreglo;
srand=(time(NULL));

for(int i=0;i<TAM;i++)
{
    *apc=(rand%(11));
    *apc++;
}

printf("El arreglo es:\n");
for(int i=0;i<TAM;i++)
    printf("%d = %d",(i+1),arreglo[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Con que opciones estas compilando?

Answer (score 0):

Puede que llegue un poco tarde pero quizás ayude a otras personas. Acabo de tener el mismo "error" en mi código, incluso cuando la última vez compilaba a la perfección. Haciendo pruebas por solventar el error borre la palabra "main" y la sustituí por otra cualquiera. Al compilar me devolvía el mismo error, pero al volver a restablecer el nombre a "main" me compilaba perfectamente

Answer (score -1):

Te falta añadir int delante de main.

```
int main(){
    .
    .
    .
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para nada, en C no es necesario agregar el tipo de retorno de `main` o cualquier otra función, aunque es solo para mantener compatibilidad con código anterior a los estándares actuales, cuando una función no tiene tipo de retorno, el compilador _suele_ asumir que es `int` lo que retorna.